# Can I change the display orientation in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: display, windows-server-2003

On a client OS like Windows XP/Vista/7, I can change my display orientation using CTRL+ALT+LEFT ARROW (UP, DOWN, and RIGHT also work).

When I try this on Windows Server 2003 R2, nothing happens. Is it just not supported on the Server OS line?  Does it depend entirely on the graphics processor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you rotate the display on your Windows XP / Vista / 7 machine you're seeing a feature of your video driver, not of the OS itself.

Answer (score 0):

Evan is incorrect about it not being in the OS.

I have two PCs in my office.  One has Win7.  In the Screen Resoluion dialog, you can change the orientation between the following values: Landscape, Portrait, Landscape (Flipped), Portrait (Flipped).

On my other box, I could do the same when Win7 was installed.  But now that Server 2008 R2 is on it (same PC/video card), that orientation option is not there any longer.  Wish it was, because this PC's monitor is a non-wide-screen 22" that can flip clockwise.

Any suggestions of a fix.  I turned on the Windows Experience feature, but the orientation option still doesn't show.